# Changing the values of Hostname with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, hostname

I am trying to change hostname of the website. Example, my url is `domain1.com/something` then it should changed to `domain2.com/something`

Code 1

```
var window = {
    location: {
        hostname: 'domain2.com'
    }
};
```

Code 2 :

```
window.__defineGetter__("location", function(){
    return {
        hostname: 'domain2.com'
    };
});
```

Also tried `document.domain = domain2.com;` but no success.

I know cross-domain is not possible in browser URL but i am just trying to change the values of page not in browser URL.

I want if i check the values using `alert(window.location.hostname);` it should show my `custom values (domain2.com)` instead of the `original values (domain1.com)`.

Comment: This smells heavily of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "*alert(window.location.hostname); it should show my custom values (domain2.com) instead of the original values (domain1.com).*" what possible reason would you have to do this? IF you want to show a custom value, you can always just do `alert(myCustomValue)`. Changing built-in provided value is *highly likely* to affect things you don't control and shouldn't control. Perhaps that's what you're trying to do. Or maybe it's not your intention. In either case it's likely to lead to errors

Comment: @VLAZ i am using some analytic tool which take data from my pages where i installed it code. I just want to manipulate them. 

So, they never come to know where i installed there code